# Installing knitr - troubles

Tags: r, knitr

I run `R 3.3.0` and `RStudio` within `Windows10` Environment. Does anyone know why I got this message trying install `knitr`. I asked this question without answer. Now I had some time and uninstalled all R versions and RStudio and installed newest. The problem did not disapeare

```
install.packages("knitr")
    Installing package into ‘\\xxxxx.se/users/Eke/xxx/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
    (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
    also installing the dependencies ‘mime’, ‘stringi’, ‘magrittr’, ‘evaluate’, ‘digest’, ‘formatR’, ‘highr’, ‘markdown’, ‘stringr’, ‘yaml’

    trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/mime_0.4.zip'
    Content type 'application/zip' length 37402 bytes (36 KB)
    downloaded 36 KB

    trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/stringi_1.0-1.zip'
    Content type 'application/zip' length 14302873 bytes (13.6 MB)
    downloaded 13.6 MB

    trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/magrittr_1.5.zip'
    Content type 'application/zip' length 149985 bytes (146 KB)
    downloaded 146 KB

    trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/evaluate_0.9.zip'
    Content type 'application/zip' length 41911 bytes (40 KB)
    downloaded 40 KB

    trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/digest_0.6.9.zip'
    Content type 'application/zip' length 169272 bytes (165 KB)
    downloaded 165 KB

    trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/formatR_1.4.zip'
    Content type 'application/zip' length 51790 bytes (50 KB)
    downloaded 50 KB

    trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/highr_0.6.zip'
    Content type 'application/zip' length 35707 bytes (34 KB)
    downloaded 34 KB

    trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/markdown_0.7.7.zip'
    Content type 'application/zip' length 167098 bytes (163 KB)
    downloaded 163 KB

    trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/stringr_1.0.0.zip'
    Content type 'application/zip' length 83487 bytes (81 KB)
    downloaded 81 KB

    trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/yaml_2.1.13.zip'
    Content type 'application/zip' length 175759 bytes (171 KB)
    downloaded 171 KB

    trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/knitr_1.13.zip'
    Content type 'application/zip' length 860259 bytes (840 KB)
    downloaded 840 KB

    package ‘mime’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
    package ‘stringi’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
    package ‘magrittr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
    package ‘evaluate’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
    package ‘digest’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
    package ‘formatR’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
    package ‘highr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
    package ‘markdown’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
    package ‘stringr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
    package ‘yaml’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
    package ‘knitr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

    The downloaded binary packages are in
        C:\Users\mali\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMnOG1B\downloaded_packages
    Error: invalid version specification ‘NA’
    In addition: Warning message:
    In utils:::packageDescription(packageName, fields = "Version") :
      no package 'knitr' was found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am adding as an answer, as I cannot add comment.

Mostly it might be permissions issue of the folder, please try installing somewhere outside your profile, for instance, in C or D drive as "D:/Rlibs".

Forgot to mention that you can always call the other/new library folder by using `.libPaths("../...")`